# Join outputs from fold/variadic expression with && operator

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, fold-expression

Function `all_checked` is meant to return `true` if all calls to `parse(...)` returned `true`, and `false` otherwise.

How can I link all the outputs together so that I effectively get

```cpp
success = parse(args[0]) && parse(args[1]) && parse(args[2]) && ...;
```

Right now, it only returns `parse(...)` for the last element.

```cpp
#include <string>

template<class T>
bool parse(const T& val)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int> || std::is_same_v<T, std::string>)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

template<class... Args>
bool all_checked(const Args& ... args)
{
    bool success = (parse(args), ...);  // should be true if all parse(...) are true
    return success;
}

int main()
{
    bool result = all_checked(1, 5.9, std::string("abc"));
}
```

I've tried other syntax like

```cpp
bool success = true;
(success = success && parse(args), ...);
```

but it did not compile.

Comment: Fix for your last syntax `((success = (success && parse(args))), ...)`. Even if `return (parse(args) && ...);` is simpler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just:

```
return (parse(args) && ...);
```

Or:

```
bool const success = (parse(args) && ...);
return success;
```

---

Your first version is folding over a comma, which discards all the results up until the last one:

```
bool success = (parse(args), ...);
```

evaluates as (let's assume three things):

```
bool success = (parse(args0), parse(args1), parse(args2));
```

which is the same as:

```
parse(args0);
parse(args1);
bool success = parse(args2);
```

The second would just need an extra pair of parentheses, but is just a very confusing way to write it anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Your fold expression should be in the form of `(<expression> <operation to fold> ...)`.  Using that your `all_checked` becomes

```
template<class... Args>
bool all_checked(const Args& ... args)
{
    return (parse(args) && ...);  // should be true if all parse(...) are true
}
```

---

You can also change

```
template<class T>
bool parse(const T& val)
```

to

```
template<class T>
bool parse(const T&)
```

so you don't get a bunch of warning about an unused variable since you never actually use `val`.